# material-ui onExited method doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formsy-material-ui

I am trying to use onExited method (Material-UI
v1.0.0-beta.41) in react js like:

```
fireOnExit=()=>{
  alert("Exited");
 }

 <button label="Cancel" onClick={this.handleClose} onExited{()=>this.fireOnExit()}/>
```

However, it doesn't work. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to link full component code?

Comment: exitedOnClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Exited")
    }<button className="button button-secondary" onClick={cancelOnClick} onExited={evt=>this.exitedOnClick(evt)}>
                                {cancelText}

Comment: Please update your question with the component code, using correct code formatting, please.

Comment: It is impossible to update it now. I can just add comments but the comments are limited in size as well

Comment: huh, right, well see my answer

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried it

Comment: right, unless you edit your question to include your component code, I don't think I can be of much use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  fireOnExit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Exited")
  }
  render() {
    return <button label= "Cancel" onClick= { this.handleClose } onExited{this.fireOnExit} />
  }
}
```